# Query about documentdb mannual snapshot

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, snapshot, aws-documentdb

About DocumentDB manual snapshot AWS official documentation says **Full backups — When a manual snapshot is taken, a full backup of your cluster's data is created and stored.**

So it means, just as an example I have created 5 snapshots of a cluster ( 1 snapshot per day ) named ss_day_1, ss_day_2,ss_day_3,ss_day_4,ss_day_5. After that if I delete ss_day_1, ss_day_2,ss_day_3,ss_day_4 then I will be able to restore whole database ( which contains data from day1 to day 5 ) from ss_day_5 snapshot.
Am I right? or do I have to keep previous snapshots to restore the database?

It will be so kind of you if you clear my doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you restore from a manual snapshot, you restore to when the manual snapshot was taken, it will be the database image at that time. In your case, if you keep just ss_day_5, it will not contain the image of the data that was in ss_day_1.

If you need to keep 5 days of backups, it is better for you to use the automatic backup feature and choose a retention of 5 days. Automatic backups are continuous and incremental, there's a full snapshot at the beginning of the retention period and then only changes are backed up. This way it will use less backup space, lower cost for your cluster. And because these changes are streamed all the time, you can also do point in time restore (PITR) up to the exact second in the past (within the retention period), which you can't do with manual snapshots.
Check [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/backup_restore-compare_automatic_manual_snapshots.html) for the comparison between the two backup methods.